# Free software to record webcam on Windows that will keep recording in background and even if the computer in locked

Tags: gratis, webcam, video-recording

Please recommend me a free software that can record video from webcam on a Windows computer.

I have tried ScreenToGif to record from webcam but it requires the program to be in foreground. If it is minimized or you open another window or lock the computer, it won't record the webcam.

So my requirement is a program what will keep recording in background (i.e. with other windows or programs in forefront, e.g. a browser) and even if the computer in locked.

Thanks.

Comment: Some ideas here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/can-i-record-video-from-my-webcam-using-media/056b676d-1d5b-46d8-9fca-449efde2cb45

Answer (score 0):

I would look at VLC and its command line options and usages. I know I can do what you are asking for using it on a Linux system, and capturing at a very very low frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg will do this, scriptable, etc.
You need to get the windows port, but syntax is relatively the same.
https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam

Answer (score 0):

I use [screenrec](https://screenrec.com/).  You can use the free version.  You don't even have to create an account.  It will also do screenshots.